# Nagios only printing part of the script's output

Tags: bash, nagios

I have a bash script that checks to make sure a backup has been created and I'm running it in nagios. The check itself works fine, but nagios isn't printing all the same output that I see when I run it in the shell.

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check whether a specified backup exists

filemask=$1

ls_output=$(smbclient \\\\Server\\Folder$ -U Domain\\Username%password -c ls | grep $filemask)
month=$(echo $ls_output | awk '{print $5}')
day=$(echo $ls_output | awk '{print $6}')
t=$(echo $ls_output | awk '{print $7}')

echo "Last Backup: $month $day $t"

today=$(date +%d)
yesterday=$(( 10#$today - 1 ))
if [ $yesterday -lt 10 ]; then
  yesterday="0$yesterday"
fi

if [ $day != $today -a $day != $yesterday ]; then
  exit 2
fi
exit 0
```

When I run this in the shell I get something like

```
Last Backup: May 24 11:03:44
```

But Nagios only shows this for output:

```
Last Backup:
```

Comment: Your command `smbclient \\\\Server\\Folder$ -U Domain\\Username%password -c ls | grep $filemask`  returns null output I think. Check that $1 is not null inside.

Comment: How is nagios running your script ? Through bash or through your default shell ? Also, try setting `set -x` at the beggining of your script to have more details about which values are in your variables

Answer (score 0):

The solution turns out to be that nagios is running inside a docker container, and so the address to the server that worked on the host was not working in nagios. Smbclient was not able to connect to the server, but the script was still exiting with a 0 exit code so nagios was green.

So the issue didn't really have much to do with nagios except for the importance of making sure that the script gives exit code 1 or 2 for any kind of error.